# The Cauchy-Crofton Formula

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, integral-geometry

I am trying to understand the most basic formula from integral geometry.  I have been looking at [this website.](http://merganser.math.gvsu.edu/david/reed03/projects/weyhaupt/project.html)

The problem is things aren't working out for very simple examples.  The circle works fine.  It has perimeter $2\pi$ and every line intersects it twice.  Placing it at the center, things are invariant under theta: $$2\pi r =L(\gamma)=\frac{1}{2}\iint\mathrm dp\mathrm d\theta=\frac{1}{2}4\pi \int \mathrm dp=2\pi r.$$  However I am having a problem for the very simple  case of the line.

**First problem resolved!**

I am having a problem for the $1\times 1$ square centered at the origin.  When I do the actual integral I get something with $\int \tan\theta\,\mathrm  d\theta$ which gives something with $\log 2$, which is not the perimeter.

If an answer can explain the square to me, I will accept it.

The square:  So the we have the $1\times 1$ square.  Lets center it at the origin.  Then we should have $$\int_0^{2\pi} (\text{radius})\mathrm d\theta.$$  By symmetries, we can take 8 times the integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  Then this is

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan \theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\log 2}{2}.$$  But this would mean the perimeter of the square is $$4\log 2$$, and I think it should be $4$.

Comment: Why do you think the integral gives $l\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The integral is indeed $2l$. By symmetry, you can write the integral as
$$
4 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{l}{2} |\cos \theta| d\theta = 2l \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos \theta d\theta = 2l\sin \theta |_{0}^{\pi/2} = 2l.
$$

Comment: @Srivatsan:  Ok what about the square?

Comment: @Srivatsan: I added some stuff

Comment: @Math Student: Where are you getting $\tan$ from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n_{\gamma}(p,\theta)$ be the number of times the line parametrized by $(p,\theta)$ intersects the curve $\gamma$. Now suppose the path $\gamma$ is actually two nonintersecting curves put together, i.e. $\alpha\cup\beta$. Then
$$n_{\gamma}=n_{\alpha}+n_{\beta}.$$
This is just basic counting: the number of times a line intersects $\alpha\cup\beta$ is equal to the number of times it intersects $\alpha$ plus the number of times it intersects $\beta$. Generalizing, if we have a square with four sides labelled $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ (let's say each is open at one endpoint and closed at the other so they don't technically intersect), then the integral splits into
$$\iint n_\alpha dpd\theta+\iint n_\beta dpd\theta+\iint n_\gamma dpd\theta+\iint n_\delta dpd\theta.$$
Now a curve's measure is invariant with respect to affine transformations, or rigid motions (this means the length of a curve is unchanged if you move, rotate, or reflect it). Thus for last three sides of the square we can perform a rigid motion in the plane that moves each one of them to simply occupy exactly the same line segment $\alpha$ occupies, so that the integral furthermore becomes
$$4\iint n_\alpha dpd\theta.$$
Your first problem of evaluating the length of a line is already resolved, so the above is
$$4\times\text{ side length}.$$
This is obviously the perimeter, as expected.

---

Suppose we want to set up the integral for the square concretely. Every line that intersects the square will intersect it exactly twice (except at some endpoints, but this will be a set of measure zero and so can be neglected). The only question is: for a given $\theta$, what values of $p$ imply that the line will go through the square? By symmetry, we'll only look at $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$ and multiply by $8$ in the end.

$\hskip 1.8in $ [image: square]

The maximum value $p$ can take for a given $\theta$ is the the base of the displayed right triangle above. But $\cos(\theta-\pi/4)=p/\text{hypotenuse}$, and that hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1/2^2+1/2^2}=1/\sqrt{2}$, so we solve for the base length $p=\cos(\theta-\pi/4)/\sqrt{2}$. Thus our formula becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(8\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\cos(\theta-\pi/4)/\sqrt{2}} 2dpd\theta\right) $$
$$=4 \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta-\pi/4)d\theta$$
$$=4\sqrt{2}\left(\sin(\pi/2-\pi/4)-\sin(\pi/4-\pi/4)\right)=4\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-0\right)$$
$$=4.$$
This is indeed the perimeter, as expected.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion is that the integral does not seem to evaluate to the side length (i.e., according to the OP), which is $2$ if you take the vertices to be at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.

Comment: @Sri: OP's integral is set up incorrectly, so I showed the easy, conceptual way to reduce the correct integral to a known form. Of course, I didn't even have to set up the original integral, so maybe it's not as helpful as it could be..

Comment: @Anon: I am upvoting your answer because it is pretty, but it is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Math Student: I have added a concrete calculation of the integral for the square. I'm betting this is what you wanted to see.